# what does the ::MainViewModel mean when pass to the singleArgViewModelFactory

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-lifecycle

in kotlin coroutines lab smaple,  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines/#6

it creates the viewModel by passing the `MainViewModel.FACTORY(repository)`

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProviders
    .of(this, MainViewModel.FACTORY(repository))
    .get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

the MainViewModel is as below,  not understand what syntax is the `::MainViewModel` used in the

```
val FACTORY = singleArgViewModelFactory(::MainViewModel)
```

the `singleArgViewModelFactory` has constructor:

```
singleArgViewModelFactory(constructor: (A) -> T)
```

which taking a function `(A) -> T`,  what does the `::MainViewModel` in the  `singleArgViewModelFactory(::MainViewModel)` mean?

```
class MainViewModel(private val repository: TitleRepository) : ViewModel() {

    companion object {
        /**
         * Factory for creating [MainViewModel]
         *
         * @param arg the repository to pass to [MainViewModel]
         */
        val FACTORY = singleArgViewModelFactory(::MainViewModel)
    }


    ......
}



fun <T : ViewModel, A> singleArgViewModelFactory(constructor: (A) -> T):
        (A) -> ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {
    return { arg: A ->
        object : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            override fun <V : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<V>): V {
                return constructor(arg) as V
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For more, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references

Comment: It is most likely a function reference to the constructor of the class.

Comment: @CommonsWare, and EpicPandaForce,   thank you all for the help to quickly point to the explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::MainViewModel` is a [function reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references). For a parameter of type `(A) -> T` it basically is a reference to a function (constructor in this case) that accepts a parameter of type `A` and delivers `T` (which in this case is the `MainViewModel` itself).

Comparing reference with its actual counterpart:

```
val ref : (A) -> T = ::MainViewModel
val ref : (A) -> T = { MainViewModel(it) } // or: = { anA : A -> MainViewModel(anA) }
```